# Aura Component Boxes in aura iteration

Tags: aura, component, iteration, size, box

How could I have some boxes with same vertical size that are being created in a iteration on aura component?

[image]

Code:

```
    <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.listPBE}" var="item">
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-1 slds-medium-size_3-of-12 slds-large-size_3-of-12" style="padding-right:1%;">
                <lightning:layout class="slds-grid_vertical-align-end slds-grid_align-center" 
                                  horizontalAlign="space" verticalAlign="center" multipleRows="true">
                <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small">
                    <div class="slds-box">
                    <p>{!item.Name}</p>
                    <p>{!item.UnitPrice}</p>
                </div>
                    </lightning:layoutItem>
                    <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small">
                <lightning:button variant="brand"
                                      label="Añadir"
                                      title="Añadir"
                                      onclick="{!c.submitDetails}"/>
                    </lightning:layoutItem>
                    </lightning:layout>
                    
            </div>
        </aura:iteration>
            
    
        </div>
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read about [ask] and take our quick [tour]. We request that you post your code as code, not as a screenshot, as it makes it easier for us to help you. You can [edit] your question to include your code.